# Pipeline which woks perfectly well on host get stuck in docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pipe, deadlock

I'm trying to execut following command:

```
tail -n +1 -f  /test/high_scan.log | awk '1,/shutting down/; /shutting down/ { exit }'
```

Inside a docker container created by:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 bash
```

The idea is to break the pipeline when awk detects the **shutting down** pattern

It works perfectly well on the host but never terminates inside the container.
The file is the same one in both cases.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` in a fresh `ubuntu:18.04` Docker container is `mawk`. On your host system, it's almost certainly `gawk`. If you install `gawk` in the container and use it instead, then it will work the same.

It looks like the particular problem is that `mawk` block-buffers its input, and once the writing process ends, `tail -f` will sit forever, so it will never read the end of its buffer. Thus, as an alternative solution, you can pass `-W interactive` to mawk if you'd rather keep using it.